# Python: Size of message to send via socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send messages using `socket` library. Since messages are variable-sized, I've decided to append the size of message at the beginning of the string, then send it. For example, if the message is

```
Hello World!
```

which is 13 characters long (I've counted EOL), I would send something like

```
sizeof13charsinbytes|Hello World!
```

via `socket.send()`, then I would split size and the message with `str.split()`

Since `socket.recv()` needs message size in bytes, how to find size of a message? I tried `sys.getsizeof()` but it gives arbitrary value for single-character string. Is it the right size?

Comment: you can send the nth packet size in (n-1)th packet's tail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its common in this situation to read the header to get the size and then read the payload. Its a bit easier if the header is fixed size (maybe a binary integer, maybe a fixed size ascii string with padding) but you can also just read character by character until you find a separator such as '|'. I've got a couple of samples below.

```
import struct

def _get_block(s, count):
    if count <= 0:
        return ''
    buf = ''
    while len(buf) < count:
        buf2 = s.recv(count - len(buf))
        if not buf2:
            # error or just end of connection?
            if buf:
                raise RuntimeError("underflow")
            else:
                return ''
        buf += buf2
    return buf

def _send_block(s, data):
    while data:
        data = data[s.send(data):]

if False:
    def get_msg(s):
        count = struct.unpack('>i', _get_block(s, 4))[0]
        return _get_block(s, count)

    def send_msg(s, data):
        header = struct.pack('>i', len(data))
        _send_block(s, header)
        _send_block(s, data)

if True:

    def _get_count(s):
        buf = ''
        while True:
            c = s.recv(1)
            if not c:
                # error or just end of connection/
                if buf:
                    raise RuntimeError("underflow")
                else:
                    return -1
            if c == '|':
                return int(buf)
            else:
                buf += c

    def get_msg(s):
        return _get_block(s, _get_count(s))

    def send_msg(s, data):
        _send_block(s, str(len(data)) + '|')
        _send_block(s, data)


import threading
import socket
import time

def client(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('0.0.0.0', port))
    print get_msg(s)
    print get_msg(s)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()

def server(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    send_msg(c, 'hello')
    send_msg(c, 'there')
    c.close()
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = threading.Thread(target=server, args=(8999,))
    c.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    client(8999)
    c.join()
    print 'done'
```

Comment: i guess, if False is for messages where size is fixed size, and if True is where it is not

Comment: is it correct to give string length and not it's size in bytes? i thought you would multiply it by the size of character but when you try to read message, you specify string length, not its size (in if True)

Comment: The example was written on python 2 where data comes in as 1 byte characters, so length and char count are the same thing. If you want a different encoding, or want to use it on python 3, then you'll have to add it.

Answer (score 6):

There's no point reinventing the wheel. Sending variable length strings is easily done by sending a string as a python string object using the `multiprocessing.connection` module. This method will allow to send most python objects, not just strings.

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.connection as connection

def producer(data, address, authkey):
    with connection.Listener(address, authkey=authkey) as listener:
        with listener.accept() as conn:
            print('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)
            for item in data:
                print("producer sending:", repr(item))
                conn.send(item)


def consumer(address, authkey):
    with connection.Client(address, authkey=authkey) as conn:
        try:
            while True:
                item = conn.recv()
                print("consumer received:", repr(item))
        except EOFError:
            pass

listen_address = "localhost", 50000
remote_address = "localhost", 50000
authkey = b'secret password'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ["1", "23", "456"]
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=(data, listen_address, authkey))
    p.start()
    consumer(remote_address, authkey)
    p.join()
    print("done")
```

Which produces something like:

```
producer sending: '1'
producer sending: '23'
consumer received: '1'
producer sending: '456'
consumer received: '23'
consumer received: '456'
done
```

Comment: Good answer but limits sender and receiver to python code.

Comment: You're very right that that is the down side. To be honest I hadn't considered the possibility.

Answer (score 4):

After serializing the data, you could simply use `len(your_serialized data)` to get its length.

Below is the sample for send and receive functions, which you could use on both client and server-side to send and receive variable-length data.

```
def send_data(conn, data):
    serialized_data = pickle.dumps(data)
    conn.sendall(struct.pack('>I', len(serialized_data)))
    conn.sendall(serialized_data)


def receive_data(conn):
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', conn.recv(4))[0]
    received_payload = b""
    reamining_payload_size = data_size
    while reamining_payload_size != 0:
        received_payload += conn.recv(reamining_payload_size)
        reamining_payload_size = data_size - len(received_payload)
    data = pickle.loads(received_payload)

    return data
```

you could find sample program at https://github.com/vijendra1125/Python-Socket-Programming.git